# How to get Folder & File name ONLY while Browsing with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So far I've been able to get only the file names from the browse button by using just jQuery and HTML file form. Here is my fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/p42Wv/2/

**MY ATTEMPT**

```
$("#file").bind("change", function() {
var elem = document.getElementById("file");
var names = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elem.files.length; ++ i) {
   names.push(elem.files[i].name);
}
var names2 = names.join('\n');
$("#filename").val( names2 );
});
```

I get the file names as I'm supposed to **BUT** how do i get the **Folder Names** as well as the file names when I select a mixed list of files and folders in the "Browse" button?

**EDIT:**

NOTE: I'm looking for Folder Name and **NOT** the **Folder Path**.
I've seen website such as Google Drive that lets user's select a **WHOLE folder** to upload. Isn't the mere extraction of folder names such an issue? If not, how does Google Drive for instance, access the subfiles of a folder and upload?

Thanks a lot,
John

Comment: Hello, so it is not possible to get the folder name that I select through the browse button? That's a bit weird because I've seen websites (Google Drive) that lets you upload a whole folder. So i am wondering why JUST the folder name can't be somehow extracted!? :O

Comment: you can get folders on chrome only using a webkit-directory attribute in an <input type=file>, input.files[], and file.webkitRelativePath on each file.

Comment: Could you please explain how Google Drive works on all browsers then?

Comment: People seem to have mistaken my question for FOLDER PATH and not FOLDER NAME and have marked it as a duplicate atrociously! A good look at the question wouldn't hurt :\ FYI to the community : https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2424368?hl=en

Comment: gdrive uses a java applet for non-chrome browsers... you can use jszip to unpack a deep/recursive zipped folder, but that's an un-wanted complication for sure...

Comment: Thank you, can I get a link to how its done on Google Chrome?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+folder+upload&gws_rd=ssl#q=firefox+%22folder+upload%22&safe=off&tbs=qdr:y

Comment: How is it done for chrome along the lines of my fiddle? Thanks

Comment: file.webkitRelativePath on files. "webkitdirectory" attribute (pardon my typo). there is a more complicated way to get empty folders using a weird chrome folder api, but you'll have to google for info on that...